# Parse PFQuery Getting User Data with PFUSER.query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get users data with Parse. I have some problem, if this problem is easy i am sorry for this.

AppDelegate -> DidFinishingLaunchingWithOptions

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
    Parse.setApplicationId("ybeCuJs2YI54aTXaV5pq31tSSmDKlsLhMusdJRPW", clientKey: "LovGLnlAFCb4jyO2HPfinsozYzYr4u1kW8XFiaJI")
```

ViewController -> ViewDidLoad

```
    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
        (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println(geoPoint)

             var user = PFUser.currentUser()!
            user["location"] = geoPoint

            if(geoPoint == nil)
            {
                println("Geopoint is null.")
            }

            var query = PFUser.query()!
            query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: geoPoint!)
            query.limit = 10
           query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (users: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if(error == nil)
                {
                    println("DATA IS COMING")
                    for user in users!
                    {
                        println(user)
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    println("**** Hava problem, Problem is: *******")
                    println(error)
                }


            }
```

**This code in ViewDidLoad method, giving this result:**

> 2015-05-12 15:27:14.879 Tinder[1727:463475] [Error]: invalid session
>   token (Code: 209, Version: 1.7.1)
>   **** Hava problem, Problem is: ******* Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=209 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 209.)"
>   UserInfo=0xXXXXXXXX {code=209, temporary=0, error=invalid session
>   token, originalError=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)"})

I have searched NSURLDomain error and 209 Code error but i couldn't find. How can i fix it?

Comment: Have you initialised Parse and set API keys etc?

Comment: @Shai, yes i have. I can save data and get CurrentUser data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Parse Installation, My Guide added this code line:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
```

I have removed this code line, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

That error is [NSURLErrorBadServerResponse](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSURLErrorBadServerResponse).  You got an HTTP 500 error back from the server.  Something went wrong server side.  If you have access to the server logs, they may tell you what the problem is.  If not, try making the same query from a browser.

Comment: Thank you for answer but i have found a different solution. I writing a new answer now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I deleted my Parse Session on parse's database..

Check if you have a session by calling:

```
PFSession.currentSession()
```